# Why after I duplicate excel and the formula are unable to read and calculate

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

xlsx file

[image]

```py
def write_data_to_sheet(sheet, column_name, data):
    # Find the column index based on the specified column name
    col_index = None
    for col in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=sheet.max_column, min_row=6, max_row=6):
        if col[0].value and col[0].value.strip().lower() == column_name.strip().lower():
            col_index = col[0].column
            break
    if col_index is not None:
        # Write data to the specified column starting from row 7
        for idx, value in enumerate(data[1:], start=6):  # Start from row 7 (Excel uses 1-based index)
            sheet.cell(row=idx + 1, column=col_index, value=value)  # Adjust row index for 1-based index in Excel
    else:
        print(f"Column {column_name} not found in sheet {sheet.title}")
```

When I manually key in data into a cell in the duplicated sheet, the formulas in other cells are able to pick up the value, and everything works as expected. However, when I use my Python script to fill in the data, the formulas in the duplicated sheet don't update.

I've tried using shutil for file duplication, translator for handling cell references, and openpyxl for writing data, but none of these approaches seem to resolve the issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before, and if so, could you provide insights into why the formulas might not be updating after using Python to populate the sheet? Any suggestions or alternative approaches to ensure that the formulas correctly generate cell values would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do not paste an image with code. Copy and paste the text of your code into your question text, then select your pasted code, and click on the icon `{}` to format it as code.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What is data and why, if you are reading data from a source sheet why not paste it directly to the destination sheet? Are you copying formulas in the cells rather than the values? If you are duplicating the workbook using shutil why do you need to use the translator? Openpyxl just changes the entry in a cell whether that be a value or a formula, nothing gets updated formula wise until the workbook is opened in Excel.